# Need to display all xml records in Gridview using Linq to XML. I need the code using which I can display xml data

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
This is XML Document.I want to bind XML data to GridView using Linq to XML .I want data from title_rec element.There are near about 94 records.  :-
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <dtg>
 <search_header>
 <plant_currency>
 <thru_date>
  <year>2012</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>15</day>
  </thru_date>
 <thru_time>
  <hour>05</hour>
  <minute>00</minute>
  <ampm>PM</ampm>
  <timezone>PST</timezone>
  </thru_time>
  </plant_currency>
 <search_date>
  <year>2012</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>19</day>
  </search_date>
 <search_time>
  <hour>01</hour>
  <minute>04</minute>
  <ampm>PM</ampm>
  <timezone>PST</timezone>
  </search_time>
  </search_header>
 <search_object type="PROPERTY" outcome="SUCCESS">
 <accepted_param>
 <title_param>
 <property_legal type="TITLE_BY_APN">
 <apn>
  <book>277</book>
  <page>312</page>
  <parcel>003</parcel>
  </apn>
  <QS n="XP" v="XA277}312 003" l="T" />
  </property_legal>
 <from_date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>05</month>
  <day>31</day>
  </from_date>
 <thru_date>
  <year>2011</year>
  <month>05</month>
  <day>31</day>
  </thru_date>
  <qualifier extended_names="YES" tt_options="SAP" />
  </title_param>
  </accepted_param>
 <search_unit type="PROPERTY" report_occurrence="01" report_count="03" outcome="SUCCESS">
 <search_param>
 <title_param>
 <property_legal type="TRACT">
 <plat type="TRACT">
 <tract>
  <number>13897</number>
  <id>1</id>
  </tract>
  </plat>
  <lot>85</lot>
 <apn>
  <book>277</book>
  <page>312</page>
  <parcel>003</parcel>
  </apn>
  <QS n="SL" v="T 13897 1$[85" l="L" />
  </property_legal>
 <from_date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>05</month>
  <day>31</day>
  </from_date>
 <thru_date>
  <year>2011</year>
  <month>05</month>
  <day>31</day>
  </thru_date>
  <qualifier extended_names="YES" tt_options="SAP" />
  </title_param>
  </search_param>
 <filters>
 <filter type="SORT">
 <path collate="ASCENDING">datatrace/response/search_group/search_object/search_unit/title_report/title_rec/date</path>
  </filter>
  </filters>
  <search_desc command="T" type="Tract" short="L:85 T:138971" long="Lot: 85 Tract: 138971" />
 <title_report record_count="91">
 <property_legal type="TRACT">
 <plat type="TRACT">
 <tract>
  <number>13897</number>
  <id>1</id>
  </tract>
  </plat>
  <lot>85</lot>
  <QS n="SL" v="T 13897 1$[85" l="L" />
  <message>PLAT HAS NOT BEEN VERIFIED</message>
  </property_legal>
  <section_index section_id="1" />
 <title_rec section_id="1">
 <date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>03</day>
  </date>
  <seq>1</seq>
 <base>
 <base_date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>03</day>
  </base_date>
 <property>
 <property_legal type="TRACT">
 <plat type="TRACT">
 <tract>
  <number>13897</number>
  <id>1</id>
  </tract>
  </plat>
  <lot>85</lot>
  <QS n="SL" v="T 13897 1$[85" l="L" />
  </property_legal>
  </property>
 <company>
  <number>08</number>
  </company>
 <order>
  <number>0052337</number>
  <tof>04</tof>
  </order>
 <inst>
  <type>SR</type>
 <recorded>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>03</day>
  </recorded>
 <posted>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>03</day>
  </posted>
  </inst>
  </base>
  </title_rec>
 <title_rec section_id="1">
 <date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>10</day>
  </date>
  <seq>2</seq>
 <base>
 <base_date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>10</day>
  </base_date>
 <property>
 <property_legal type="TRACT">
 <plat type="TRACT">
 <tract>
  <number>13897</number>
  <id>1</id>
  </tract>
  </plat>
  <lot>85</lot>
  <QS n="SL" v="T 13897 1$[85" l="L" />
  </property_legal>
  </property>
 <company>
  <number>08</number>
  </company>
 <order>
  <number>0052337</number>
  <tof>04</tof>
  </order>
 <inst>
  <type>SR</type>
 <recorded>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>10</day>
  </recorded>
 <posted>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>10</day>
  </posted>
  </inst>
  </base>
  </title_rec>
 <title_rec section_id="1">
 <date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>13</day>
  </date>
  <seq>3</seq>
 <base>
 <base_date>
 <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
 <day>13</day>
  </base_date>
 <property>
 <property_legal type="TRACT">
 <plat type="TRACT">
 <tract>
  <number>13897</number>
  <id>1</id>
  </tract>
  </plat>
  <lot>85</lot>
  <QS n="SL" v="T 13897 1$[85" l="L" />
  </property_legal>
  </property>
 <company>
  <number>08</number>
  </company>
 <order>
  <number>0052600</number>
  <tof>04</tof>
  </order>
 <inst>
  <type>SR</type>
 <recorded>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>13</day>
  </recorded>
 <posted>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>13</day>
  </posted>
  </inst>
  </base>
  </title_rec>
 <title_rec section_id="1">
 <date>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>25</day>
  </date>
  <seq>4</seq>
 <title_doc>
 <property>
 <property_legal type="TRACT">
<plat type="TRACT">
 <tract>
  <number>13897</number>
  <id>1</id>
  </tract>
  </plat>
  <lot>85</lot>
  <QS n="SL" v="T 13897 1$[85" l="L" />
  </property_legal>
  </property>
 <inst>
  <year>1980</year>
  <number>220434</number>
  <type>RL</type>
 <recorded>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>25</day>
  </recorded>
 <posted>
  <year>1980</year>
  <month>11</month>
  <day>25</day>
  </posted>
 <image provider="DATA_TREE" county_fips="065" document_id_desc="DocumentYear.DocID">
 <image_params document_type="DAILY_DOCUMENT" index_type="YEAR.DOCID" document_index_id="16">
  <description>1980.220434</description>
  </image_params>
  </image>
  <QS n="IN" v="Y1980220434" l="B" />
  </inst>
 <party_info>
 <party role="GRANTOR">
  <name>RECORD OWNER</name>
  <QS n="GN" v="RECORD OWNER" l="N" />
  </party>
  </party_info>
 <remarks>
  <len>9</len>
  <text>80 139134</text>
  </remarks>
  </title_doc>
  </title_rec>
  </title_report>
 <commentary>
 <comment>
  <text>ADJOINING PROPERTY SEARCH SUPPRESSED</text>
  </comment>
 <comment>
  <text>ALL TRACT SEARCH SUPPRESSED</text>
  </comment>
  </commentary>
  </search_unit>
  </search_object>
  </dtg>
```

I have created class TitleByApn & written Linq to XML Queries to parse xml data. Please find below class details and the code which is returning the query output. Please use this code or if you can provide me some other code with different logic that is also fine.

```
public class TitleByApn
{
 private string grantor;
 private string grantee;
 private string doctype;
 private string instrument;
 private string month;
 private string  day;
 private string  year;
 private string remarks;

 public string _grantor
{  get { return grantor; }
}

public string _grantee
{
 get {return grantee ;}
}

public string _month
{
 get {return month; }
}

public string _day
{
 get {return day; }
}

public string _year
{
 get { return year; }
} 

public string _doctype
{
get{ return doctype; }
}

public string  _remarks
{
get {return remarks;}
}

public string  _instrument
{
get {return instrument; }
}

public static List<TitleByApn> GetTitle()


        {

            List<TitleByApn> output = new List<TitleByApn>();
            string filepath = @"C:/Title.xml";

            //XElement xdoc = new XElement();

              XElement xdoc =   XElement.Load(filepath);

            //XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(filepath);

            //var query = from b in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc")
            //            select b.Value;

            //string query = (from b in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc")
            //                select b.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            int i = 0;
            string s1 = "";
            string inst = "";
            //string s2 = "";
            //string s3 = "";
            //string s4 = "";
            var authorList = xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
            foreach (string item in authorList)
            {


                     string Month = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("recorded")
                                 select o.Element("month").Value).First();

                string Day = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("recorded")
                               select o.Element("day").Value).First();

                string Year = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("recorded")
                                select o.Element("year").Value).First();

                string granTor = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("party_info").Descendants("party")
                                   where o.Attribute("role").Value == "GRANTOR"
                                  select o.Element("name").Value).FirstOrDefault();
                ////select new Instrument()

                ////{
                ////    Grantor = (string)o.Element("name")

                ////};

                string granTee = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("party_info").Descendants("party")
                                   where o.Attribute("role").Value == "GRANTEE"
                                  select o.Element("name").Value).First();

                string Doctype =(from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("inst")
                                   select o.Element("type").Value).First();

                 string instNo = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("inst")
                                   select o.Element("number").Value).First();

                  string REmarks = (from o in xdoc.Descendants("title_doc").Descendants("remarks")
                                   select o.Element("text").Value).First();

               output.Add(new TitleByApn(granTor, granTee, Month, Day, Year,instNo, Doctype, REmarks));


                }


            return output;
             } 

}

This is the code responsible to bind the class to gridview:
GridView1.DataSource = TitleByApn.GetTitle();
            GridView1.DataBind();


I know because of FirstOrDefault() only first record is displaying in gridview.
I want code to display all the records in gridview.
Please help me ASAP.
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Can I recommend starting small?  Use a tiny XML, containing one or two nodes and then get that working.  Once that's working, add another node and make it more complex, one small step at at time.

Comment: Thanks for responding.I have already tried by using small but still I am not able to display data.Please help me ASAP.

Comment: Hi All, I need to display null or empty if the string element is not present in xml document. I have used below code but still not getting null or empty: var granTee = from o in xmlDoc.Descendants("title_rec").Descendants("party_info").Descendants("party")
                          where o.Attribute("role").Value == "GRANTEE"
                          select new { grantee = (string)o.Element("name").Value ?? String.Empty}; I have already posted the xml above. My xml document elements are not consistent and sometime element is not present. Can anybody help me.

Comment: The code you wrote in the comment above returns a list.  If you want to return null if the list is empty, you could do something like if(!granTee.Any()) return null;  I still stand by what I said earlier... if you want more help, you should post the simplest possible version of the code that isn't working correctly.  Once you're helped with that, post again when you get stuck with something more complex.

Comment: Is this what you wanted?  var granTee = from o in xmlDoc.Descendants("title_rec").Descendants("party_info").Descendants("party") where o.Attribute("role").Value == "GRANTEE" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)o.Element("name").Value) select new { grantee = (string)o.Element("name").Value };

Answer (score 0):

Based on the content of your question, it sounds like you've already parsed your XML and placed it into a class you created above.  This tutorial found on Codeplex titled, "[A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial#introduction_apis)
" goes into very good indept detail on how to bind your class to a DataGridView complete with access modifiers and so forth.

Essentially, once you create your GridView, you can add a BindingSource object to it's data item, and simply add your XML class information as such:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 airplaneBindingSource.Add(new Airplane("Boeing 747", 800));
  airplaneBindingSource.Add(new Airplane("Airbus A380", 1023));
  airplaneBindingSource.Add(new Airplane("Cessna 162", 67));
}
```